# Object related errors

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and during my learning I am getting two different kinds of errors on different lines while referencing a value of an existing sheet to be put on a new sheet:

For this part of the code I am getting the error "Object variable or With block variable not set",

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
For Each wss In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If wss.Name = "Optimisation" Then
        found = True
        wss.Delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not found Then
    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ws1.Name = "Optimisation"
End If
ws1.Cells(1, 1).Value = "RECIPE" '<----- error 
'ws1.Range(“A1”).Value = “RECIPE” <----- same error
```

Sometimes, when  I run the code I get another error instead of the one above.
For this part of the code I am getting the error "Run-time Error: Object Required"

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Application.ActiveSheet
Dim Newrecipe As String
Newrecipe = ws2.Cells(currentrow, currentcolumn).Value '<----- error
```

I tried `set NewRecipe = ws2.Cells(currentrow, currentcolumn).Value` in response to the error. However, now I am getting a "Compile error: Object Required" for:

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Application.ActiveSheet
Dim Newrecipe As String
set Newrecipe = ws2.Cells(currentrow, currentcolumn).Value '<----- error
```

Could someone please explain to me why these errors are occurring? Thank you.

Comment: You've not assigned an existing worksheet to `ws2` in either of your last two code blocks. Do you expect a worksheet to just magically appear when you declare a variable? Your first code block assigns one correctly when it adds a new worksheet, but only if `found` is false - presumably, the error occurs when found is true. If you want to access an existing worksheet, you also have to assign one to `ws2` before you can use it.

Comment: My apologies, it was in the code but I mislooked it and didn't include it here, I have edited the code above.

Comment: Well, that explains that error. You set `found` to true, and then delete the sheet it found (which means it doesn't exist), but you only create the new sheet if found is false, which means you never create the sheet. You then access the variable without ever assigning anything to it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have removed the `if not found` and `end if` and it works perfectly! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looks like I was too late with my response, good job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first error might be because your code isn't running the following code.

```
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
ws1.Name = "Optimisation"
```

Only if the code in the () is true will the `If () Then` execute. in your case you have `Not found`. So if you do have a sheet called Optimization then you are setting `found = true` and then you are asking Not found. If `found = true` then `Not found = false`. Now that you have false, the code inside your if statement never executes.

And for your second error, you definitely wouldn't use set since a string is a native type of variable to VB. Its the objects that are specific to excel that you usually need to use set for. Pretty much any number, string, array (variant), boolean, date doesn't need set. I'm sure there are others I'm missing, but just think if you would see this type of variable in a different language, you probably don't need a set.

I'll update my answer when I figure out why you get the error without the set though.

Just a question, where are `currentrow` and `currentcolumn`being initialized at?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping through all sheets look to find the existing sheet directly.

Code below also prevents a warning message to the user (suppressing DisplayAlerts).

```
Sub Recut()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set ws1 = Sheets("Optimisation")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not ws1 Is Nothing Then
'if found delete without alert
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws1.Delete
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Else
    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ws1.Name = "Optimisation"
    ws1.Cells(1, 1).Value = "RECIPE"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is really useful for me, thank you for sharing!